# Remove all style scripts and html tags from a file and generating a new file in a different folder using python

Tags: python

I am stuck with this code which removes all HTML tags however whenever I try to make it read the file it makes it read the source path and also the file name how do I make the code not do this ?
This is my code:

```
import os, re 

#Paths
src_path = "/content/CS13309_Archivos_HTML/Files" 
dest_path = "/content/CS13309_Archivos_HTML/Nuevos_Archivos" 

files = os.listdir(src_path)

for file in files: 
    # open the file using its name 
    file_name = file.split(".") 
    open_file = open(src_path + file_name[0] + ".html", "r",encoding='latin1') 

    # parse the file for style scripts and html tags
    style_scripts = re.compile('<style.*?>.*?</style>')
    html_tags = re.compile('<.*?>')
    stripped_data = re.sub(style_scripts, '', open_file.read())
    stripped_data = re.sub(html_tags, '', stripped_data)

    # create a new file without style scripts and html tags
    new_file = open(dest_path + file_name[0] + 'NuevosArchivos.txt', 'w+')

    # write the content from the old file to the new file
    new_file.write(stripped_data)

    # close the opened file 
    open_file.close() 
    new_file.close()
```

This is the error Im getting:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/CS13309_Archivos_HTML/Files307.html'`
I tried using BeautifulSoup but its the same Error...

Comment: And you've verified that path exists? Don't think you have a folder content in your root directory, did you mean to use a relative path? Also the for loop body is not indented correctly.

Comment: Thanks for answering @BRemmelzwaal Yep, the path exists, I just want to read all the files and then create a new ones but in an other folder.

Comment: The error indicates `Files307.html` is not found, are you sure it's the correct name?

Comment: I think you are not understanding me... My problem is that I am declaring the source path and on the other hand I am also reading the file name. The file name is 307, while the source path is Files. How do I get it to read it from one address and then create those other files in another address? @BRemmelzwaal

Comment: If the source path is `.../Files/307.html`, shouldn't you add an extra forward slash to `src_path`?

Comment: isn't missing the separator? `src_path + "/" +  file_name[0] + ".html"`. use `os.path.join` for path operations

Comment: Yes, you are correct @BRemmelzwaal it was only a Slash... smh. Anyway, thatnks for your time (:

Comment: No problem, hopefully it will help your debugging skills in the future :)